# Diffraction and phase jumps

Tags: geometric-optics, diffraction

I have been researching diffraction for the purposes of implementation into a ray tracer (based on the geometrical theory of diffraction). However, I found a few statements that seem conflicting to me with regards to the phase jumps at a diffraction location. The Kirchhoff diffraction formula, for example, can be solved to get a phase jump of 90° at an aperture, the same goes for the Rayleigh-Sommerfeld diffraction integral. On the other hand, with the GTD or the UTD, the diffraction coefficients include phase jumps of usually 45° (see e.g. the original paper by [Keller](https://capmimo.ece.wisc.edu/capmimo_papers/keller_geom_th_diff.pdf) ). In all cases, the fundamental physical conditions seem to be the same to me, a wave is propagated to an aperture/half-plane and then creates diffracted waves. So where do these different phase jumps come from? Also, are these dependent on whether or not the aperture is bound by a perfect conductor?

Comment: I do not think, but am not sure, that the $\pi/2$ in the Kirchhoff and the $\pi/4$ in the Keller formulas are not related. The phase *shift* in the Kirchhoff formula already shows up in Fresnel's construction of the Huygens wavelets representing free space propagation, see Born and Wolf, Chapter 8.2. The Keller phase *jump* comes from Sommerfeld's edge current that is induced by the incident wave. this issue is discussed in detail in Chapter 11.5, specifically Eq. 34 and starts in Chapter 8.9 but note a warning: it is not for the faint hearted, and, unfortunately, I am one of those...

Comment: @hyportnex then I guess I will see how faint-hearted I am and take a look at that, thanks.

Comment: If you are that enterprising you may wish to read the original Sommerfeld: Mathematical Theory of Diffraction, Springer-Birkhauser, 2004, DOI 10.1007/978-0-8176-8196-8 This is a recent English translation of the German original from 1895. In general Sommerfeld is quite readable, but you must know complex analysis and Riemeann surfaces and some such.

Comment: @hyportnex then I might as well read the original German version (because I am German), thanks for recommending. And here's to hoping I remember enough analysis from my first semesters of university...

Comment: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.212701/page/n259/mode/2up?view=theater